# Hormann garage door opener automation with Loxone

Tags: home-automation, low-voltage

I own a Hörmann Supramatic 3 garage door opener and in my house I've also set up [Loxone](https://www.loxone.com) home automation system, so I decided to connect the opener to the automation system, so I can control the garage door remotely.

For that to work I needed to buy a [UAP](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tor7.de%2Fhoermann-universaladapterplatine-uap-1&edit-text=) (universal adapter, meant for uses like these) and connect it to my Loxone miniserver.

I found [this guide](https://github.com/netdata/loxone/blob/master/hormann-Garage-door-via-Loxone.md), which made the setup easier and I've setup everything accordingly.

The status (fully closed, fully open, mid drive) works perfectly fine, however I am having issues with the motion commands (move up, move down, stop), as they only work sometimes and in some directions - which is most likely due to me wiring it up incorrectly (however the guide linked above is not very specific about the wiring etc).

Currently I use the Loxone Relay Extension (basically classic relays) through which I wired a cable on which I run 24V DC if the relay is on.

On the UAP it connects to input 10, 17, 15 and 23 where 10 + 17 is wired to one relay and 15 + 23 to another. I am an electronics amateur and can't figure out based on the schematic below if that is correct?

Currently I send a 0.5 impulse through when you press open/close in the home automation system - as that's similar to how the garage door remote control works, but not sure this is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the Guide you posted

The UAP enables you to

```
control the light of the supramatic
open the garage door
close the garage door
stop the garage door 
check whether the door is totally closed or totally open, light status?
```

That tells me that it appears your UAP will not allow for the individual movements that you are looking to achieve.
The only things I get from what is stated is that if you press to open - you press the button again to stop it (not a true move up move down motion).

That being said you might be able to program a button to activate open when pressed and to also activate the same function on release.

Looking at the other link for the Hormann website using translation - it looks like they indicate it can do a partial open : "for controlling the partial opening and the drive lighting"

I do not see any manual on their site for this unit.

I see one for your supramatic (seems a bit over complicated for a Garage Door) - however reading the instructions for the ventilation position You might find what you need here. http://www.hormann.co.uk/fileadmin/_country/hoermann.uk/dok/SupraMatic_Series_3.pdf

6.1.13 
Menu 43: Changing the 
ventilation position
▶ 
See Figure 
28
The partial opening position (ventilation 
position) depends on the door type and 
is pre-set at the factory.
Sectional door:
Approx. 260 mm slide 
travel before the 
Close
end-of-travel position.
Minimum 
height
Approx. 120 mm slide 
travel before each 
end-of-travel position.
The partial opening position is triggered 
using the 3rd radio channel (menu 13), 
an external receiver, the additional print 
UAP 1 or an impulse at terminals 20 / 23.
To change the partial opening 
position:
1. 
Move the door into the desired 
position with the buttons 
 and 
, 
via the taught-in radio code 
impulse
or an external control element with 
impulse function.
2. 
Select menu 
43
.
3. 
Press the 
PRG
 button until the 
decimal point next to the menu 
number is illuminated.
The changed partial opening position 
is saved.
If the selected height is too low, a 2-digit 
number starting with 
1
 will appear with 
a flashing decimal point (see section 17)

Comment: Hi Ken, as you say in the beginning of the reply the UAP enables me to "open the garage door" and "close the garage door" which is what I want to achieve (same as what the person who wrote the guide I linked to achieved), sorry if I didn't explain properly. So I basically want a remotely  controlled button (the app) where I click open and it will start moving up until the end position, which should be possible, and it sometimes does move or open, but something must be off with the connection, impulse duration or voltage as it does not work consistently :) Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 0):

I’m just looking at this as I’m trying to achieve the same function with my own garage door and loxone system. 
Could it be that you 0.5 pulse is too short? The remotes require a 2 second press to avoid accidental presses, have you tried making your pulse longer?